# Retrieve access token in Azure with Ruby SDK/APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, azure-sdk-ruby, azure-sdk-for-ruby

I am trying to retrieve access token using azure app client id and client secret . Initially I tried with the following python code block

```
import adal
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    "https://management.azure.com/",
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET)
```

This is returning the token without any issue .
I am trying to do the same using Azure Ruby SDK following the contents in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby but still not able to get any sample to follow .
I am a beginner in ruby ,can some body please share their experience with me on this ?

**Added to my post from here on**

Hi ,
Many thanks for your support .
I followed you code and written my code like the below one following your code

```
require 'adal'

TENANT=<TENANT ID>
CLIENT_ID= <CLIENT_ID>
CLIENT_SECRET =<CLIENT_SECRET >
AUTHORITY = "https://login.windows.net"
auth_ctx = ADAL::AuthenticationContext.new(AUTHORITY, TENANT)
client_cred = ADAL::ClientCredential.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
result = auth_ctx.acquire_token_for_client("https://management.azure.com/", client_cred)
puts result.access_token
```

But I am getting an error like the following ,
check_host': bad component(expected host component)

In Python it worked for me though .

Following is the full error trace .

```
F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:593:in `check_host': bad component(expected host component): [https://login.windows.net] (URI::InvalidComponentError)
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:634:in `host='
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:668:in `hostname='
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:187:in `initialize'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:134:in `new'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:134:in `build'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/http.rb:62:in `build'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/authority.rb:95:in `token_endpoint'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/token_request.rb:228:in `oauth_request'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/token_request.rb:182:in `request_no_cache'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/token_request.rb:171:in `request'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/token_request.rb:84:in `get_for_client'
    from F:/All_Ruby_On_Rails/ruby-2.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/adal-1.0.0/lib/adal/authentication_context.rb:78:in `acquire_token_for_client'
    from F:/Selenium_Workspace_HSBC/dsi/azureadallogin.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

It looks to me the AUTHORITY constant has the issue .Can anybody provide some clue here ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question with 2 things: 1) Include the Ruby code that you have written (you have only shared Python code which works) and 2) What are the issues you're running into.

Comment: the AUTHORITY should be hostname and not an URI. Just change it to login.windows.net (stripping out the https://), and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Welp, he's the copy\paste:

```
# Create authentication objects
token_provider = MsRestAzure::ApplicationTokenProvider.new(tenant_id, client_id, secret)
credentials = MsRest::TokenCredentials.new(token_provider)
# Create a client - a point of access to the API and set the subscription id
client = Azure::ARM::Resources::ResourceManagementClient.new(credentials)
client.subscription_id = subscription_id
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/master/management/azure_mgmt_resources

Comment: Hi ,I tried and it is working .Thanks for your help .I am trying to do the same using username and password in python .The method there is like context.acquire_token_with_username_password .Any clue on the ruby equivalent one ?

Comment: I'm not the biggest expert in Ruby, but looking at [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/b67599812a9caa654515bbb72a267d67a0890e45/runtime/ms_rest_azure/lib/ms_rest_azure/credentials/application_token_provider.rb) it looks like there's no password grant flow with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can use the [ADAL for Ruby](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby) library to get the access token like using Python ADAL as the code you post.

First of all, install `adal` via `gem install adal`.

Then,

1. Follow the `adal` [sample with `CLIENT_ID` & `CLIENT_SECRET`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/tree/dev/samples/authorization_code_example) to get the access token via the code below using the method `acquire_token_for_client`.

   ```
   require 'adal'
   AUTHORITY = 'login.windows.net'
   auth_ctx = ADAL::AuthenticationContext.new(AUTHORITY, TENANT)
   client_cred = ADAL::ClientCredential.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
   result = auth_ctx.acquire_token_for_client("https://management.azure.com/", client_cred)
   puts result.access_token
   ```
2. Follow the `adal` [sample with `USERNAME` & `PASSWORD`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/blob/dev/samples/user_credentials_example) to get the access token via the code below.

   ```
   require 'adal'
   AUTHORITY = 'login.windows.net'
   user_cred = ADAL::UserCredential.new(username, password)
   ctx = ADAL::AuthenticationContext.new(AUTHORITY_HOST, TENANT)
   result = ctx.acquire_token_for_user("https://management.azure.com/", CLIENT_ID, user_cred)
   puts result.access_token
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Updated my original question .Please have a look

Comment: @Soumen The `AUTHORITY` value is `login.windows.net` without `https://`. I updated my sample code, please try it.